# Can I tap Rupture Spire to pay for its own ability with an Amulet of Vigor in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Assuming I stack the abilities correctly can I get the [Rupture Spire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRupture%20Spire%5d) untapped in time to pay for its own ability with an [Amulet of Vigor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAmulet%20of%20Vigor%5d)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

When Rupture Spire enters the battlefield, 2 different abilities trigger. The next time someone (usually you) you would gain priority, you put both of those abilities on the stack, in an order you choose.

> 603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities they control on the stack in any order they choose.

Choose to put Rupture Spire's ability on the stack first, with Amulet of Vigor's on top. Amulet of Vigor's ability will resolve first, untapping Rupture Spire.

Then Rupture Spire's ability will resolve, at which point you are free to tap Rupture Spire for the 1 mana you need to pay.

**A key point here is that Rupture Spire's ability doesn't do anything until it resolves; it does not require mana payment ahead of time.**

You also have priority between Amulet of Vigor's ability resolving and Rupture Spire's ability resolving. You could just tap Rupture Spire at this time and float the 1 mana until Rupture Spire's ability resolves. Either of these would result in the same net effect. It's just like the difference between tapping a Mountain and then casting [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d); or beginning to cast Lightning Bolt and tapping a mountain to pay for it when you get to the pay costs part of casting.